# Where does the .ToList() go in LINQ query result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When getting data to populate a data grid, I have always pulled the data, made a list and mapped to my model, like this:

```
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var data = _db.Person.ToList();
        List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Person person = new Person()
            {
                PersonId = item.PersonID,
                FirstName = item.FirstName,
                LastName = item.LastName
            };
            People.Add(person);
        }
        return People;
    }
```

This works fine, but in the interest of writing less code I discovered the .Select method and (what I think is) anonymous type. So now I have:

```
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return _db.Person.Select(d => new Person
        {
            PersonId = item.PersonID,
            FirstName = item.FirstName,
            LastName = item.LastName
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Though it is not as easy to read, this works fine too.  Is there a preference either way?

Comment: FYI `new Person` -> not anonymous type.

Comment: "Though it is not as easy to read, this works fine too" - in what way is it not as easy to read? It's more natural in my view... every bit of the code you've got expresses something you want - the source, the transformation you want to apply on each person, and finally the conversion to a list.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Person` object from an existing `Person` object?  Are you just "truncating" to those three columns?

Comment: My thinking was, a List of Persons should be filled with Persons, so I create a new List, then create a new bunch of new Persons to go in it. Not sure if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second would be preferred in most cases.  The main differences are:

1. The second example will turn your projection into a SQL statement, only returning the columns you ask for.
2. The first example creates 2 lists, one of which is temporary and will be eligible for garbage collection relatively quickly.  This may be an issue if the `People` table is fairly large.

Note that if you did not have `ToList()` after `_db.Person` the two methods would be virtually identical.

And you are not creating an anonymous type since you *specify* the type (`Person`).  To create an anonymous type you would just have `new {... properties ...}`

> Though it is not as easy to read,

I think that once you get used to Linq statements like `Select` you'll find it *very* easy to read.

Comment: *The second example will turn your projection* There is even a side-effect to this... The object won't be "saved" into the context in EF and in other similar ORMs

Comment: @xanatos that's a good point - I've added a comment asking the OP if the new object creation is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The Select approach is preferred for several reasons.

1. Instead of calling toList, you can return the IQueryable so that additional operations like where clauses can be added before pulling data into memory rather than pulling large chunks of data into memory and then filtering it
2. Select allows you to select only the fields you care about rather than pulling all columns into memory and just using select few rows. 
   e.g. if the Persons entity also has Age column on it that you do not care about, the select approach will not reach that into memory while the first one will